# Add Admin CODE to feature collection

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, region

I want to add the ADMIN2_CODE from the dataset FAO/GAUL/2015/level2 to a featurecollection I have created to get information on some forests in Wales. I have added the elevation to the polygons but I can't work out how to add the (first) ADMIN2_CODE. My code doesn't work - can someone help please - I know I am doing something blatantly wrong!

```
var fromList = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2");

var filter = ee.Filter.inList('ADM2_NAME', ['Gwent']);
var filteredArea = fromList.filter(filter);

Map.setCenter(1.1, 51.5, 8);
Map.addLayer(filteredArea, {}, 'Regions');

var gfc2018= ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2018_v1_6').clip(filteredArea);

var lossImage = gfc2018.select(['lossyear']).gte(7);
var lossBand = lossImage.and(gfc2018.select(['lossyear']).lte(20));
var zones = lossBand.updateMask(lossBand.neq(0));

// Add the loss layer in red.
Map.addLayer(lossImage.updateMask(lossBand),
            {palette: ['FF0000']}, 'Loss 2007 onwards');

var area_threshold = 300; // about 30 hectares?

// Define whole county as a region
var geom = filteredArea.geometry();

// Convert the zones of the forest loss areas to vectors.
var vectors = zones.addBands(zones).reduceToVectors({
  geometry: geom,
  crs: lossBand.projection(),
  scale: 30,
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  eightConnected: true,
  labelProperty: 'zone',
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count()
}).filterMetadata("count","greater_than", area_threshold);

// Make a display image for the vectors, add it to the map.
var display = ee.Image(0).updateMask(0).paint(vectors, '000000', 1);
Map.addLayer(display, {palette: '000000'}, 'vectors');

var SRTM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003"); // exampleelevation image

var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(SRTM);

// add min, max and mean elevation of each geometry
var reducers = ee.Reducer.median()
                .combine(ee.Reducer.min(), 'Elevation', true)
                .combine(ee.Reducer.max(), 'Elevation', true)
                .combine(ee.Reducer.mean(), 'Elevation', true);

vectors = SRTM.reduceRegions(vectors, reducers, 30);

// Get Admin Districts
var fromList = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2");
var filter = ee.Filter.inList('ADM0_NAME', ['Romania']);
var filteredArea = fromList.filter(filter);

var AreaName = filteredArea.aggregate_first("ADM2_CODE")

reducers = ee.Reducer.first();

// This next line is wrong!
vectors = AreaName.reduceRegions(vectors, reducers, 10);

// Export the FeatureCollection to a CSV file.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: vectors,
  description: 'Forest',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to add a column with a static value to each row of your exported CSV, you can do this:

```
vectors = vectors.map(function (feature) {
  return feature.set('The ADM2 code', AreaName)
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/23bb206da0b8ae06f7c11c587ab3a3b8

Comment: Hi Daniel - OK - that does save something out but it just appears to be one value. I have changed the code a bit to be the whole of wales and I want the ADM2_CODE for each polygon in the featirecollection. But (fairly obviously) it just gets the first one for the whole of Wales and puts that one in - any ideas?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/033e21dd3ca0423c42ac91e942d4c661